# terraform console: Extra characters after expression

Tags: terraform

I installed terraform and trying to do eval basic expression.
I am getting weird errors.

e.g what's wrong with this expression?

```
variable "BN" { default = "X" }
```

or

```
x = 3
```

for loops works but it needs to be wrapped into square brackets.

```
[ for bn in [1, 2, 3] : "%{if bn == 2} ok %{else} bad ${bn} %{endif}" ]
```

terraform console makes impression that you made a syntax error, but I think at most it could be semantic one.
As for now this utility looks very limited.

Is there any other place I can play with terraform where?

Comment: First two expressions are fine. Third expressions requires `[]` because that is the constructor for a `list` in the language: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming). Lambdas generally need that in programming when you want a different return type.

Comment: Terraform is a great tool for converting configuration files into a network, which then produces a dependency order deployment plan. It's a poor tool if you're using it as a general purpose language to manipulate strings and integers. Your best bet if you want to play with it would be creating a free tier cloud account and implementing a function with backing storage.

Answer (score 2):

Of the three examples you shared, only the third one is actually a Terraform language [expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/index.html). An expression is something that generates a value which you can then assign to a resource type argument.

Your first example is a variable declaration. The string you assigned to its `default` argument is an example of an expression - a literal string expression - but that overall block declares a new variable in a configuration, so it's not something you can evaluate to produce a value.

Your second example seems to assigning the value `3` to an argument called `x`, but that doesn't mean anything without some additional context: `x` would need to be an argument inside a block in order to be meaningful, and even then it wouldn't be an *expression*, but rather the definition of an argument called `x` using the expression `3`.

If you want to experiment with the Terraform language then the best way to do it is to make a file whose name has the suffix `.tf` in a new directory, and then run the main Terraform commands `terraform init`, `terraform plan`, etc in that directory. The `terraform console` command is for evaluating hypothetical expressions against your configuration, but until you've actually written a configuration you'll have nothing other than literal values to refer to.

Comment: Everything to the right of the assignment operator (the equal sign, "=") is an expression within Terraform (source: I am a Hashicorp Authorized Instructor and it is the official guidance of Hashicorp).  The documentation that you cited suggests the same.